# How to change HTML when I click on a button? JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, button, dom-events

I'm new in coding so I will try to explain my problem the best I can. I have data from an api and i want to add a button that will return the most popular stories based on points. The function is working in console (i get the most popular stories) but i can't make HTML to change.

```
const popularity = document.getElementById("popular");
popularity.addEventListener("click", () => {
  var mostPopular = stories.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.points - a.points;
  });
  return mostPopular.forEach((story) => {
     `
    <div class="story">
    <div> 
        <span class="gray">${story.index || ""}</span>
        <a id="bar" href="${story.url}">${story.title}</a>
        <span>(${story.domain})</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="gray">
          ${story.points} points by ${story.user} ${story.time_ago}
          |
          <a href="#/item?id=${story.id}">
            ${story.comments_count} comments
          </a>
          |
          <span class="favorite gray" data-story='${JSON.stringify(story)}'>
            <img class="heart" src="heart-logo.png">
            ${story.isFavorite ? "Remove From Favorites" : "Add To Favorites"}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      
    `;
  });
});
```

Comment: You're iterating through the array and constructing a large chunk of HTML but not actually doing anything with that HTML. You presumably want to assign it as the `innerHTML` of some element?

Comment: You are returning a `undefined` because `forEach` doesn't return anything. You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem clearly. You should tell what exactly is problem and what should be your expected result...

Answer (score -1):

Instead of forEach, I presume you want to construct in-memory a HTML portion to be later inserted. Instead you might want to consider to [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) your sorted array into a String (HTML) with [Element.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) for example:

```js
const HTMLStories = mostPopular.reduce((html, story) => {
  html += `<div class="story"> ${story.title} etc... </div>`;
  return html;
}, "");


someElement.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", HTMLStories);
```